# Interactive shop system not working

Tags: python, list, tuples, global

```
money = 0    
Pickaxes = {
 'adamant pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'bronze pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'dragon pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'inferno adze  ': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'iron pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'mithril pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'rune pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5},
 'steel pickaxe': {'cost': 100, 'speed': 5}}

def shop():
    global cost
    print "Welcome to Alister's goods!"
    time.sleep(2)
    sellbuy = raw_input("\nWould you like to sell or buy goods?:\n")
        if sellbuy == "sell":
            sell()
        else:
            print "\nHere is a list of our goods....\n"
            for i in Pickaxes:
                print i
            what_item = raw_input("\nWhich item would you like to purchase?\n")
            if what_item in Pickaxes and money >= Pickaxes[what_item]["cost"]:
                    inventory.append[what_item]
                    print "You have successfully purchased a", what_item
                    start()
```

my shop definition stops working when you type the item you want in the raw_input it just stops the program with no errors, this is part of a bigger program thats why its within a definition etc....

Thanks

Comment: Is your real code correctly indented? Look at the input string - will `==` match all characters? How about trailing `\n`?

Comment: Yes, in the program i have everything is properly indented and such the problem seems to be coming from the: if what_item in Pickaxes and money >= Pickaxes[what_item]["cost"]:
            inventory.append[what_item]
            print "You have successfully purchased a", what_item
            start()

Comment: Looks like it's working as designed. I don't see an `else` block for handling what happens when you don't have enough money to buy the item you want. So when you have 0 money, then the function will end without producing any more output.

Comment: By the way, why did you name/tag your question `tuple`/`list` - you're dealing with a dictionary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, the money is 0, meaning it will never enter that condition, and the program just exits. (You probably want to also add something that reduces the money after the purchase while you are at it)

You should catch that condition,

```
if what_item in Pickaxes:
    if money >= Pickaxes[what_item]["cost"]:
        inventory.append[what_item]
        print "You have successfully purchased a", what_item
        start()
    else:
        print "Not enough money"
        start()
else:
    print "No such item"
    start()
```

or loop buying in a while loop:

```
while True:
    what_item = raw_input("\nWhich item would you like to purchase? (Leave blank to quit)\n")
    if not what_item:
        break # exit the loop
    if what_item in Pickaxes:
        if money >= Pickaxes[what_item]["cost"]:
            inventory.append[what_item]
            print "You have successfully purchased a", what_item
            break # exits the loop
        else:
            print "Not enough money"
    else:
        print "No such item"
```

Comment: Much cleaner than the original

Comment: Don't forget to charge the customer for his purchase (which means you also need to declare `money` as a `global`). I'm removing my answer, yours is much nicer.

Comment: Thank You i've implemented the while loop into my program, now i get an error like this: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @Ali That is completely unrelated (And you will have to give more information than that), if you want to ask a new question about it - you are more than welcome to, in the meanwhile If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [Accept my Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/192545).

Comment: Im really sorry, im quite new to this yes your answer did help alot thanks, Accepted.